# Having count(*) MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT
dnum
, SUM(IF(salary>20000, 1, 0)) AS Employee
FROM project 
INNER JOIN works_on
ON pno=pnumber
INNER JOIN employee
ON dno=dnum
GROUP BY dnum HAVING COUNT(*) >2
```

I first want to determine whether each department has more than 2 employees or not, if true then get the department number and count of the employees. But only those who make higher than 20,000.

The way I have done it, it shows correct results for one of the departments, but for others it shows a complete wrong count. For example, for department 4 it shows 18, but the correct count should be only 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WHERE salary > 20000` instead, there is no need to use `CASE` for it:

```
SELECT 
  dnum, 
  COUNT(*) AS Employee
FROM project 
INNER JOIN works_on ON pno = pnumber
INNER JOIN employee ON dno = dnum
WHERE salary > 20000
GROUP BY dnum 
HAVING COUNT(*) >2;
```

You might also need to use `COUNT (DISTINCT EmployeeNumber)` instead if there is duplicate numbers.

Comment: Yeah, I first used WHERE but because it gave wrong results I thought maybe it has something to do with WHERE. I used COUNT(DISTINCT essn) and it works now. I still don't understand why it gave a higher count, because there is nothing in the database to imply 18. Thanks.